# Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I really confuse with the way we create dictionary in swift. So could you please tell me what is the different between

```
var myDic3 = [String : AnyObject]()
```

and

```
var myDic2 = Dictionary <Int,AnyObject>()
```

and

```
var myDic4 = [ : ]
```

When i declare like myDic4 I cannot add key and value for it:

```
myDic4["001"] = "ABC"
```

And the error is "**Cannot assign to the result of this expression**"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Swift, you can declare and initialize an empty Dictionary with type `String` for keys and type `Any` for values in 4 different ways:

1. `var myDic1 = [String : Any]()`
2. `var myDic2 = Dictionary<String, Any>()`
3. `var myDic3: [String : Any] = [:]`
4. `var myDic4: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]`

These will all give you the same result which is an empty Dictionary with `String`s as the keys and `Any`s as the values.

`[String : Any]` is just shorthand for `Dictionary<String, Any>`.  They mean the same thing but the shorthand notation is preferred.

In cases 1 and 2 above, the types of the variables are inferred by Swift from the values being assigned to them.  In cases 3 and 4 above, the types are explicitly assigned to the variables, and then they are initialized with an empty dictionary `[:]`.

When you create a dictionary like this:

```
var myDic5 = [:]
```

Swift has nothing to go on, and it gives the error:

> Empty collection literal requires an explicit type

**Historical Note:** In older versions of Swift, it inferred `[:]` to be of type `NSDictionary`.  The problem was that `NSDictionary` is an immutable type (you can't change it).  The mutable equivalent is an `NSMutableDictionary`, so these would work:

```
var myDic6: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
```

*or*

```
var myDic7 = NSMutableDictionary()
```

but you should prefer using cases 1 or 3 above since `NSMutableDictionary` isn't a Swift type but instead comes from the Foundation framework.  In fact, the only reason you were ever able to do `var myDic = [:]` is because you had imported the Foundation framework (with `import UIKit`, `import Cocoa`, or `import Foundation`).  Without importing Foundation, this was an error.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to vacawama's answer If you would like to use different types  for the dictionary keys you need to use [AnyHashable: Any]:

edit/update:

**Swift 3 or later**

```
var dict:[AnyHashable: Any] = [:]

dict[1] = "one"
dict["two"] = 2

print(dict)  // [AnyHashable("two"): 2, AnyHashable(1): "one"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following declarations are all identical ways of declaring an empty Dictionary of type < String, Int > in Swift:

```
var dictionary1 = [String:Int]()
var dictionary2: [String:Int] = [:]
var dictionary3 = Dictionary<String, Int>()
var dictionary4: Dictionary<String, Int> = [:]
```

And these are identical ways of declaring an empty NSMutableDictionary in Swift:

```
var dictionaryA = [NSObject:AnyObject]()
var dictionaryB: [NSObject:AnyObject] = [:]
var dictionaryC = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
var dictionaryD: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = [:]
var dictionaryE = NSMutableDictionary()
var dictionaryF: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
```

So many choices! I put both lists in my order of preference due to readability, but I would think "NSMutableDictionary()" would be prefered method if mixing with ObjectiveC or using with methods that take NSMutableDictionary parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDic1 = Dictionary <String,AnyObject>()
```

is the "old" way of creating an empty dictionary with a String as a key type and AnyObject as a value type.

This one is the "modern" way and does the exact same thing:

```
var myDic2 = [String:AnyObject]()
```

But if you try to create one with this:

```
var myDic4 = [ : ]
```

you can't use it like a Swift dictionary because the array is not typed so Swift creates an NSDictionary instead.

**But**, you can use this notation to *empty* a Swift dictionary:

```
myDic1["001"] = "ABC"
println(myDic1["001"]) // Optional "ABC"
myDic1 = [:]
println(myDic1["001"]) // nil
myDic1["001"] = "ABC"
println(myDic1["001"]) // Optional "ABC"
```