# How to create news feed UI in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have create a news feed app. I get a news data from server. In my data news available on text OR image with text(same as Facebook feed).
I have successfully create before in UITableviewCell images with text content, but I am trying to many time in UITableViewCell text or images with text, Both multiple cell first cell is only text and second cell is image with text. How to create, I know i am not explain proper way but i want to create a same as Facebook feed(TimeLine).

And Which type of array or dictionary create this view. some cells in text view and some cells image and text view. How to create dynamic cell. I am so confused. How to create news feed ui and in which type of array create this news feed. Please help. I am new in IOS. Thank you.

Please find the attachment and see ones. I want to like this.

Only text view
[image]

Image and text view

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `UILabel` and `UIImageView` as you normally would in a cell. (I would suggest a `UILabel` instead of a `UITextView` if you are only displaying the text, correct me if I'm wrong). Setup your constraints for the label to have a leading, top and trailing. Set its `numberOfLines` to be 0 and content mode to `word wrap`. Now for your `UIImageView`, add a top to the `UILabel`. Leading, trailing and bottom to `superView`. Now also setup a height constraint for your `UIImageView` that will be a minimum value. Create an `IBOutlet` for this constraint inside your cell.

Now, in your `UIViewController` set the `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` property and also `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimensions`. Soo now, inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, whenever your cell contains an image set the height constraint to be the minimum value otherwise set it to 0.

Edit:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

  //select your model from the array corresponding to your indexPath.row
  CustomModel *model = array[indexPath.row]

  // I am assuming you are fetching image from server
  NSString *imageUrlString = model.imageUrl

  //check your model if it contains an image
  if(imageUrlString){
      cell.imageHeightConstraint = 250.0f;
  }else{
      cell.imageHeightConstraint = 0.0f;
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand all points please explain only [cellForRowAtIndexPath] how to image set  the height constraint to be the minimum value otherwise set it to 0. Please explain some code

Comment: I'm familiar with Objective - C, soo I have added that, maybe it will help you figure it out in swift.

Comment: one more thing please solve my last problem. It's a big confusion in my mind. Normally create a array  'var products: [String] = ["ponds", "lakme", "milk"] and image array   var images: [String] = ["logoimg.png", "logoimg.png"]. image array object only two. so my question is how to decide image load in which cell. otherwise how to create dictionary in this define pair. the news text of the same image.

Comment: I think i am not explain proper. please try to understand and please support

Comment: how to decide which cell image load and which cell only text load

Comment: Please create a normal array include a text and images OR only text

Comment: your edited answer  CustomModel *model = array[indexPath.row] is a text array and second line NSString *imageUrlString = model.imageUrl in this imageUrl is a array?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom tableViewCell which will contain textView and imageView according to your requirements. And go through the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170922/creating-custom-tableview-cells-in-swift)

And for the different type of datatypes you have to create a dictionary(or array of dictionary) of key value pair. Please visit the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049265/dictionary-in-swift)

If you have two types of feeds one with image and another without it, then you may create two different custom cells and use them accordingly.

Another option is to make imageView's height as zero by creating an outlet of constraint.But I won't support this, this should be used sparingly.

It's better to create an array which contains dictionary.
where you dont have image just set value of "image" to empty string.

```
    var dict1:[String:String] = ["text":"my text....","image":"imagename.png"]
    var dict2: [String:String] = ["text": "my text...", "image":""]
    var myDictArray = [[String:String]]()
    myDictArray.append(dict1)
    myDictArray.append(dict2)
```

while placing them in uitableviewcell just check the dictionary value for the key "image". If it's not empty then load the first custom cell(with imageView and textView) else load the second custom cell(without imageView)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I also create custom tableviewCell, but array of dictionary reload in tableview that time some cells image not available only text available. This condition how will manage image view hide or not

Comment: It's not compulsory all cells available in image. both condition how will manage

Comment: Put an placeholder image and replace it with your image later after its downloaded.

Comment: NO NO I want to image is not available in my some feeds so that condition how to hide image view

Comment: I want a facebook timeline view, some cell onle text show and some cell image with text show

Comment: Suppose i created two custom cell, But how to decide which cell image load and which cell only text load . please explain cellForRowAtIndexPath method and code

Comment: how to create dictionary this type of view

Comment: @DivankKumawat added some code snippet. May it will help